# Binary file Reading, add extra characters in c?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I try to read binary(executeable) files, butsome problem as it prints extra character(0xffffff) after every few bytes. But this code work perfectly for text file(Non-binary). The code is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  uint64_t i=0;
  FILE * fp=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
  uint8_t a;
  long int size=0;
  char *msg;
  size=findSize(argv[1]);
  msg=(char *)malloc(size+1);

  while((a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
  {
    printf("%02x",a);
      msg[i]=(char)a;
    i++;
    if(i==size)
      break;
  }
  i=0;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    printf("%x",msg[i]);

  }
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to print the value(s) of **a**, It works perfectly, while printing **msg[i]**, it prints extra bytes i,e:

**Orginal bytes:** `0xa31c4b1ab66b900`

**Output with extra bytes:** `0xa31c4ffffffb1ffffffafffffffb66ffffffb900`

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an int value. So, `a` should be defined as an int.

Comment: ... which is especially important when reading binary data, to distinguish `EOF` from `0xFF`.

Comment: Default parameter promotion converts a `char` to an `int` when passing to `printf`. This include sign extensions for negative values.

Comment: and the `fgetc` thing **is** relevant when you're working with binary files

Comment: also `long` might not be sufficiently large to contain every file size, but it perhaps wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *msg;
```

Your `msg` variable has datatype `char`, which is probably signed on your platform. That means, it represents values from -128 to +127.

```
printf("%x",msg[i]);
```

Any arguments to `printf()` that have an integer datatype smaller than `int` will be expanded to `int`. That conversion will keep the arithmetic value, so -128 which is `0x80` in `char`, will expand to `0xFFFFFF80` for `int`.

To avoid this, you need to store or cast the values to `unsigned char` first. The `uint8_t` type is same as `unsigned char` and easier to read, so:

```
printf("%x", (uint8_t)msg[i]);
```

That way the numeric value will range from 0 to 255, like you would expect, and print as `0x00` to `0xFF` even after the implicit conversion to `int`.